# If I import a file, does the imported file need to have the html tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I have one index file and use jQuery to dynamically load other files into divs that are contained in the index file.

My question is: must the file I import have all the HTML tags like `<html>`, `<head>`, `<title>` and all the rest or can it just be the HTML needed to render the page? That is, the HTML and content between the two `<body>` tags.

Because nobody (browsers or search engines) see the imported tags that do not display content. In other words the search engines only see the content between the two `<body>` tags.

Comment: It would be **really** useful if you could show how you're loading the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they don't assuming you are importing them directly.

Your file would like like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
   <body>
    <div>
     INCLUDE
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Say your file looks like:

```
<p> I am a paragraph </p>
```

The resulting file would look something like this:

```
 <html>
      <head>
      </head>
       <body>
        <div>
         <p> I am a paragraph </p>
        </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Which would be valid HTML.
If you were to include all the tags it would look like this:

```
 <html>
          <head>
          </head>
           <body>
            <div>
              <html>
          <head>
          </head>
           <body>
            <div>
             <p> I am a paragraph </p>
            </div>
           </body>
        </html>
            </div>
           </body>
        </html>
```

Which is both a mess and not valid.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question right, it's fine if the files are just HTML fragments, since you're loading them and adding them to a fully-formed page.